# jQuery Mobile Anchor Behaviour

Tags: jquery-mobile, anchor

I'm testing a simple anchor link with jQuery mobile. I noticed two undesired actions when dealing with anchors.

- Navigating to another page by clicking on the anchor is taking around
  3-4 seconds to complete (which is not the case if I use non-jQuery
  mobile anchor).
- As soon as the navigated page is loaded, an AJAX request is fired
  off whose URL is the previous page (the page where the anchor link was present).

The first behavior might be happening because I'm using a couple of extra files (css and js) needed by the jQuery mobile framework, but the second point is the one which is more troubling. How do I prevent the ajax request from firing?

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="content">
     <p>                    
        <a href="first-page.php" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">First Page</a>
        <a href="second-page.php" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Second Page</a>
        <a href="third-page.php" data-role="button" data-ajax="false">Third Page</a>                     
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try `rel="external` instead of `data-ajax="false"`. If you dont want to use jQM Ajax at all, you can disable it completely `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;`. "_jQuery Mobile will automatically handle link clicks and form submissions through Ajax, when possible. If false, URL hash listening will be disabled as well, and URLs will load as ordinary HTTP requests_"

Comment: ok try this code, load it after jQ.js and before jQM.js in head. `$(document).on("mobileinit", function () { $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false; $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false; });`

Comment: So should I put `$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;` in a `$(function())` block?

Comment: no, bind it to `mobileinit` as in my previous comment.

Comment: Nah..still the ajax is firing up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43569/discussion-between-omar-and-asprin)